# Showing multiple timer function in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timer

I am trying to display two timer on a webpage with different start times.

First timer only shows for 5 seconds and then after 10 seconds I need to show timer2. 
I am very new to Angular and have put together following code.

It seems to be working fine except when the settimeout is called the third time it doesn't work correctly and it starts going very fast.

Controller

```
 // initialise variables
$scope.tickInterval = 1000; //ms
var min ='';
var sec ='';

$scope.ti = 0;
$scope.startTimer1 = function() {
    $scope.ti++;
    min = (Math.floor($scope.ti/60)<10)?("0" + Math.floor($scope.ti/60)):(Math.floor($scope.ti/60));
    sec = $scope.ti%60<10?("0" + $scope.ti%60):($scope.ti%60);
    $scope.timer1 =  min + ":" + sec;
    mytimeout1 = $timeout($scope.startTimer1, $scope.tickInterval); // reset the timer
}

//start timer 1
$scope.startTimer1();

$scope.$watch('timer1',function(){

    if($scope.timer1 !=undefined){
        if($scope.timer1 =='00:05'){
            $timeout.cancel(mytimeout1);
            setInterval(function(){

                $scope.startTimer2()
                $scope.ti = 0;

            },1000)
        }
    }

})

//start timer 2 after 2 mins and 20 seconds
$scope.startTimer2 = function() {
    $scope.ti++;
    min = (Math.floor($scope.ti/60)<10)?("0" + Math.floor($scope.ti/60)):(Math.floor($scope.ti/60));
    sec = $scope.ti%60<10?("0" + $scope.ti%60):($scope.ti%60);
    $scope.timer2 =  min + ":" + sec;
    mytimeout2 = $timeout($scope.startTimer2, $scope.tickInterval);
}


$scope.$watch('timer2',function(){

    if($scope.timer2 !=undefined){
        if($scope.timer2 =='00:05'){

            $timeout.cancel(mytimeout2);

            setInterval(function(){

                $scope.startTimer1();
                $scope.ti = 0;

            },1000)


        }
    }

})
```

In my view I simply have

```
<p>{{timer1}}</p>

<p>{{timer2}}</p>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use setInterval but $interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically starting multiple startTimer function so it's adding up. If i understood your problem well you don't even need to have all those watchers and timeouts.
You just can use $interval this way :

```
$scope.Timer = $interval(function () {

  ++$scope.tickCount

  if ($scope.tickCount <= 5) {
    $scope.timer1++
  } else {
    $scope.timer2++
    if ($scope.tickCount >= 10)
        $scope.tickCount = 0;
  }
}, 1000);
```

Working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h535xase/13/)

Comment: Thank you, but I need to display two "count up " timers  in minutes:seconds format. When the first one reaches 02:00 then it needs to stop /pause and second timer should start from 00:01.Once second timer reaches 02:00 it pauses and then the first one recycles again. Hence I was using watches.

Comment: check the new fiddle, it should be what you're looking for - note that i didn't formated the timers, but you could use your code sample on the integer to format it to mm:ss

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to solve my issue efficiently.